# How to correctly restrict access to some folders via htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have such directiry structure:

```
- www
    - folder1
        - folder2
            - folder21
            - folder22
            - folder23
```

I allowed all image files to be accessed

```
<FilesMatch \.(?i:gif|jpe?g|png)$>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all 
</FilesMatch>
```

I allowed all all files in certain folder to be accessed

```
<FilesMatch /folder2/folder22/.*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all 
</FilesMatch>
```

I allowed all `robots.txt` files to be accessed

```
<FilesMatch (robots\.txt)$>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all 
</FilesMatch>
```

And at the end I added password restriction

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Personal use"
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

But when I try to access any image file via browser, I get password prompt.
Could anyone explain how to fix it and what might be the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Order Deny,Allow` means that the `deny` rules are processed before the `allow` rules. Therefore, you will get a password prompt.

For any folders and filetypes that you want to allow access, just put the below config into your `.htaccess`:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all 
    Satisfy Any
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: It helped only for images rule. Tryed this rule `/folder2/folder22/.*` and it prompted me for password too.

Comment: Use `<Directory>` directive for the folders.

Comment: It use isn't allowed in `htaccess` and I can configure only from there.

Comment: `echo "Satisfy any" > /path/to/folder2/folder22/.htaccess` and try again.

Comment: So it should be outside `FilesMatch` bloks? Also I need `.htaccess` file to be in upper level directory, not inside `/path/to/folder2/folder22/`.

Comment: Your statement about the order processing order is correct, but the conclusion is not. Apache evaluates all matching rules in the order you specified and then takes action according to the **last matching rule**. Yes, it's a it uncommon these days but you have to keep that in mind when designing access rules in Apache.

Comment: Solved the problem, but it did cost. I ended up creating 3 `.htaccess` files. One under `folder1` with password import and two others where: one in `folder22` and other in `folder23` with plain simple `1: Allow from all 2: Satisfy Any`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a `satisfy Any` directive to each of the `FilesMatch` blocks.

```
<FilesMatch \.(?i:gif|jpe?g|png)$>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any    
</FilesMatch>
```